# $cordovaSocialSharing share on ios

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm using ngcordova plugin social sharing: all worked fine on android, but on ios the title (subject) doesn't appear.

```
function shareEventDetail() {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(
        function () {
          $cordovaSocialSharing
            .share(null, title, null, urlEvent) // Share via native share sheet
            .then(function (result) {
                 // Success!
            }, function (err) {
                 // An error occured.
            });
        });
}
```

html :

```
<button class="button" ng-click="shareEventDetail()"></button>
```

Comment: you need to test that app in the real device and also check whether plugin is installed for ios you can check by going to platforms->ios->platform_www in that path check the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's the behaviour depend on which phone you use.
so just you can play it dirty , you can append all the data you want in message field (first parameter)